# How to display the Facebook like count in WordPress theme

Tags: plugins, theme-development, facebook

I have added the Facebook like button and Facebook comments plugin from Facebook's developer website to my WordPress theme.

I have used the below code to display the Facebook comment count.

```
<fb:comments-count href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>"></fb:comments-count>
```

The like button works fine but the counts is itself displayed on the like button. I know there is something called Facebook graph. Eg. http://graph.facebook.com/site-url. 
How do I use this or something similar to also show like counts on post meta data section.

I'm trying to create something like this: Posted 1 day ago | 4 Comments | 5 Likes

Comment: Check this out for all your Social media counts: [https://wordpress.org/plugins/social-count-plus/](https://wordpress.org/plugins/social-count-plus/)

Comment: Thanks @VishalPhulia but I was trying to do it without any wordpress plugin :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Misha Rudrastyh made a great guide you can follow [here](https://rudrastyh.com/facebook/get-share-count-for-url.html), I'll include the relevant code here as well.

```
/*
* Display number of shares using WordPress HTTP API
*
* @param integer $post_id We want to get number of shares of the post with this ID
*/
function wp_get_shares( $post_id ) {
    $cache_key = 'misha_share' . $post_id;
    $access_token = 'APP_ID|APP_SECRET';
    $count = get_transient( $cache_key ); // try to get value from Wordpress cache

    // If no value in the cache
    if ( $count === false ) {
        $response = wp_remote_get('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/?id=' . urlencode( get_permalink( $post_id ) ) . '&access_token=' . $access_token );
        $body = json_decode( $response['body'] );     
        $count = intval( $body->share->share_count );
        set_transient( $cache_key, $count, 3600 ); // store value in cache for 1 hour
    }
    return $count;
}
```

Add this to your theme's functions.php-file. Now you can use `echo wp_get_shares($post->ID);` anywhere you like.

Comment: I have 2 questions. 
I'm using WP Super Cache plugin so will it update the like count in real time? And as you suggest to follow the Misha Rudrastyh's guide, He have also explained the similar functionality using JQuery, I can use this method but then I have to expose my app secret to the public in script.js file. Will it be safe? As Facebook recommends to keep it concealed.

Comment: In the code I've included, the result is stored in the cache for 1 hour – I'm not sure how WP Super Cache will treat this, but no - it will not update the count in real time. It's a good idea to store the result for at least some time, to avoid hitting your [rate limit](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting).

Comment: Regarding the question regarding safety about a publicly visible app secret in the script.js, I'm not the right guy to answer that, have a look at [this answer](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19989/facebook-api-app-secret-possible-misuse).

Comment: Thank you, I've read the answer and as I expected it should be strictly secret. I'll go with the Former option with 30 mins caching time.